# C# how to reach resource in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to play the media element (not that it's matter I'm asking a global question here).
I have a resource file for the media element which I wanna play but it's source demand a URI for example

```
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(@"c:\users\SabrinaVazIsFuckingGod\video\22.wav");
```

now i dont have `22.wav` as a path but in my "resource"

[image: My File]

I found out from my searching that some programmers are talking about packs
but I dont know how to use them,
so please if you know how, and can explain me or even better to give me example code I'll be grateful.

Thanks for the people who already answered, but they didnt answered my question, I want to have my media file in the exe and not in any other place.

Comment: Sabrina Vaz is one lucky gal.

Comment: The link you gave states it all, so what is the problem? did you change the property of the .wav file to resource? just change the URI to `new URI(@"/Resources/22.wav")`

Comment: no sorry it is not working i got an erorr while running if using your code http://s12.postimg.org/5fo1390bh/Sabrina_178.jpg

Comment: Finally, someone with on SO with a sense of humor and is not completely dead on the inside and isn't a complete jerk to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I was able to get the following to work:

```
MyMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
MyMediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"Resources\AudioFile.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

If you go to the properties of your media file in Visual Studio and set the Build Action to `Content`, and Copy to Output Directory to `Copy if newer`, that should do the trick. I tried playing around with the pack syntax you mentioned, but if these media files are going to be copied on build to a sub-folder alongside your executable, a simple relative path should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to **Build Action** to set as **Resource** and use following code

```
uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/22.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know packages yet but the document you linked indicates that you should have the `pack://` prefix, then an authority (which would be `application:///` as your file is in your resources, but with the `///` replaced by `,,,` as the note explains) so that your URI would be of the form:

```
new URI(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/22.wav")
```

Try that and see if it works.